# Showing sum diverges

Tags: probability, divergent-series

I am working on a homework problem and 
I was wondering if someone could possibly give me
a hint (or a solution) on how to show that the sum $\sum_{k\geq 1} (1- Q_k)$ diverges,
where
$$
Q_k = \sum_{0 \leq j \leq \lfloor 2^k/k \rfloor }
{2^k-kj \choose j} (-p^{k}(1-p))^j - 
p^k\sum_{0 \leq j \leq \lfloor 2^k/k - 1 \rfloor }
{2^k-kj-k \choose j} (-p^{k}(1-p))^j,
$$
and $p \geq 1/2$.

I would also like to note that $1-Q_k$ is what I computed as the probability that a {0,1} string of length 2^k contains a 0-block of length greater than or equal to k if the occurrence of 0 has  probability p and 1 has probability 1-p.

Thank you very much!